# Why the following method is dislayed in the console without using console.log at the end?

Tags: javascript

Hi I would like to know why when I set up the following var, without using `console.log(jakubpresentation)` I can see it anyway??

```
var jakubpresentations = jakub.presentation("formal", " morning ");

var jakub = {
  name: "jakub",
  surname: "klos",
  age: 18,
  profession: "designer",
  presentation: function(style, timeOfDay) {

    if (style === "formal") {
      console.log("good " + timeOfDay + this.name + " Welcome in DesignUX Company")
    } else if (style === "nonformal") {
      console.log("Hi" + this.name + "Welcome in DesignUX Company");
    }
  }
}

var justyna = {
  name: "justyna",
  surname: "rybicka",
  age: 28
}

var jakubpresentations = jakub.presentation("formal", " morning ");
```

Comment: Because that's just what the console does. It prints the value of the last statement executed.

Comment: What basically every console does, yes.

Comment: Because assignment is an *expression* in JavaScript, the value of which is the value that got assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the value of `jakubpresentations` to the value returned from the function `jakub.presentation`.

```
var jakubpresentations = jakub.presentation("formal", " morning ");
```

When you set a variable equal to a function call, the function runs. The entire function will execute. The `console.log` statement is inside the function you run.

```
presentation: function(style, timeOfDay) {
  if (style === "formal") {
    console.log("good " + timeOfDay + this.name + " Welcome in DesignUX Company")
  } else if (style === "nonformal") {
    console.log("Hi" + this.name + "Welcome in DesignUX Company");
  }
}
```

You can run a function by using it to create a variable. You don't have to give it an entire line of its own.